# How can I update an image encoded in Base64?

Tags: wordpress, base64

I've been asked to change the text on a logo used in a Wordpress website. I thought this would be a quick job but I've discovered that the logo is pulled into the website in **Base64 code** (data:image/svg+xml;base64,) I cannot find any jpg/png version anywhere to edit. The CSS has the Base64 code in it which is called from the header.php page.

Can anyone tell me the steps I need to take to update this logo when it has been encoded into Base64?

Many thanks.

Comment: why don't you try to get the image from base64 using http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter?

Comment: I can get the image this way but if I edit this how can I update it to the live site. Do I need to save it as a svg file, how do i know the dimensions of this file - should it be the same dimensions as it appears on the site, does the image need to be transparent? Once i've edited the image do I then need to encode into Base64 and replace the code in the CSS? Thanks

Comment: Imho, you just need to use the previous image as a base for the new image. As with svg, I think you don't need to change the dimensions and leave it intact like the previous image dimensions. After creating the image, you just need to encode it to base64 and replace the code in CSS. Just try it first, I don't think it will do any harm for you ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi i still can't get this to work. I decoded the base64 currently being used in the CSS for the logo, then I edited the resulting image. I encoded this edited image and put the code in the CSS I was careful to maintain the data:image/svg+xml;base64 in the code string. However the logo space showed blank and no image was visible. I've cant figure out what i'm doing wrong. Do i need to upload the image anywhere? When i decoded the base64 the logo was huge (600px x 700px) the logo is determined in the CSS to be 300x50px but I edited the larger file thinking thats what I needed to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by converting the image to a png and base64 encoding it - this worked. For some reason the svg version of the file encoded wouldn't work.